# Integrity constraint violation: cakephp

Tags: cakephp, constraints, integrity

I trying to detele question option but that question id belongs to other table, but it showing this error.

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`carbonate-staging`.`course_assesments_multiple_choices`, CONSTRAINT `A_q_Q_UID` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `course_assesment_questions` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACT)

SQL Query: DELETE `CourseAssesmentQuestion` FROM `carbonate-staging`.`course_assesment_questions` AS `CourseAssesmentQuestion` LEFT JOIN `carbonate-staging`.`courses` AS `Course` ON (`CourseAssesmentQuestion`.`course_id` = `Course`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `carbonate-staging`.`course_units` AS `CourseUnit` ON (`CourseAssesmentQuestion`.`course_unit_id` = `CourseUnit`.`id`) WHERE `CourseAssesmentQuestion`.`course_id` = 601 AND NOT (`CourseAssesmentQuestion`.`id` = (384))

So **I just want to delete questios and its choice option after question delete**. Please help me on this.

Comment: You're trying to delete the question first and then all the question options? If the options refer to the question, that's the problem. Delete the options first, then the question. Or use Cake's associations to delete those dependent option records automatically when you delete the question.

Comment: Can you refer an example for this?

Comment: For the automatic deletion of dependent records? Would need to know specifically which version of Cake you're using.

Comment: I am using 2.6 version of cake php

Comment: For Cake 2.x, set the [cascade](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/deleting-data.html#delete) parameter to the `delete` function to `true` when deleting the parent (question) record.